# How to take all borders out of button except top border?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make button 2 look exactly like button 1 with a border-top property. But I'm getting grey lines on three sides on Button 2.

css:

```
.button {
  background-color: black;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Button1</a>
<button class="button">Button2</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reset border first(note that order is important):

```
border: none;
border-top: 2px solid red;
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button1</a>
<button class="button">Button2</button>
```

Comment: All answers were useful. I like yours best.

Comment: Thanks & You’re welcome !

Answer (score 3):

Add an id to button. Then include the following lines of code in your CSS file.

```css
#btn2{
      border-bottom: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
    }
```

```html
<button class="button" id="btn2">Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override default border properties of button with the following properties

```
border-bottom: none;
border-right: none;
border-left: none;
```

or you can also remove default border of button by `border: none` then write your desired border-property like `border-top: 2px solid red`.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.button {
  background-color: black;
  border-top: 2px solid red !important;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button1</a>
<button class="button">Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your border is still set for the other sides, try removing the other sides first then adding the border top. Or, alternatively just set the `border-size: 2px 0 0 0;` and `border-color: red;`.

```css
.button {
  background-color: black;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button1</a>
<button class="button">Button2</button>
```

Hope this helps,